# Node.js socket hang up error when connecting to twitter api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting `socket hang up` error , when connecting to twitter streaming api with basic authentication using https. I think the error is occurring when doing the authentication.

```
var https = require("https");
var options = {
        host: 'stream.twitter.com',
        path: '/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=bieber',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer('UserName' + ":" + 'Password').toString("base64")
        }
}; //end of options


var request = https.request(options, function(response){
            var body = '';
             console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
             console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));

            response.on("data", function(chunk){
                    var tweet = JSON.parse(chunk);
                    console.log("Tweet " + tweet.text);
            });  // end of data

            response.on("end", function(){
                console.log("Disconnected!!");
            }); // end of end

            response.on("error", function(){
                console.log("error occured");
            }); // end of error
}); // end of request

request.on("error",function(error){
        console.log("Error: " + error.message);
                }); // end of error
```

When i try to access this url it works fine.

```
https://username:password@stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter
```

Comment: This error has been included in NodeJS 0.8.20 (as you can see in https://raw.github.com/joyent/node/v0.8.20/ChangeLog). It occurs when socket connection ends. I have experimented this error with code that works perfectly with previous Node versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `https.request(options, function(response){ }` to `https.get(options, function(response){ }`  Thanks to Darrenlooby on nodejs IRC for pointing it out.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 3):

You can use https.request, but make sure you add:

```
request.end();
```

where `request` is the object returned from `https.request`

See http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback for an example.

I had the same issue and this fixes it :)